# blockchain - Student Management System - Custom Data Structure

Tags: blockchain

I'm new to blockchain and trying to learn the same. I'm creating Student Management System, wherein students will enroll themselves in training program, these training program will have batch associated. I'm trying to build a basic data structure for this requirement.

Please suggest, if I can have all these information as part of blockchain's block or keep student, training prg and batch information as private storage i.e each entity will have separate storage, and have the blockchain block to store only the ID's of each object i.e. student id, training prog id and batch id for which student has enrolled?

Please suggest.

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

From programmer perspective blockchain works very similar to CQRS system, where you have separate model for modification commands and queries.

Please read more about "CQRS and event sourcing".